# How to filter pd.Dataframe based on strings and special characters?

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, special-characters

Here is what I have:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
d = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Desc': ['0*1***HHCM', 'HC:83*20', 'HC:5*2CASL', 'DM*72\nCAS*', 'HC:564*CAS*5']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

Output:

   ID          Desc
0   1    0*1***HHCM
1   2      HC:83*20
2   3    HC:5*2CASL
3   4   DM*72\nCAS*
4   5  HC:564*CAS*5
```

I need to filter the dataframe by column "Desc", if it contains "CAS" or "HC" that are not surrounded by letters or digits.

Here is what I tried:

```
new_df = df[df['Desc'].str.match(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]CAS[^A-Za-z0-9]|[^A-Za-z0-9]HC[^A-Za-z0-9]') == True]
```

It returns an empty dataframe.

I want it to return the following:

```
   ID          Desc
1   2      HC:83*20
2   3    HC:5*2CASL
3   4   DM*72\nCAS*
4   5  HC:564*CAS*5
```

Another thing: since 3rd row has "\nCas", where "\n" is a line separator, will it treat it as a letter before "CAS"?

Please help.

Comment: But HC:5*2CASL has a digit before it?

Comment: If either "HC" or "CAS" is not surrounded by letters and numbers, it should return the above dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.loc[df['Desc'].str.contains(r'(\W|^)(HC|CAS)(\W|$)', flags=re.M)]

# If you don't want to import re you can just use flags=8:

df.loc[df['Desc'].str.contains(r'(\W|^)(HC|CAS)(\W|$)', flags=8)]
```

Result:

```
   ID          Desc
1   2      HC:83*20
2   3    HC:5*2CASL
3   4   DM*72\nCAS*
4   5  HC:564*CAS*5
```

To answer your other question, as long as `\n` is passed correctly it will be parsed as a newline character instead of an alphanumeric character `n`.  i.e.:

```
r'\n' -> `\\n` (backslash character + n character)
'\n' -> '\n'   (newline character)
```

For further explanation on the regex, please see Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/FNBgPV/2

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate "not a digit" in this code? if i understand correctly it only checks if there is a letter before/after.

Comment: I have an issue: if there is a line like this "DM*72\nCAS5*", the code returns it, although it does contain a digit after "CAS", so it shouldn't return it, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: There is no issue with "\n", but if, for example, i take this line "DM*72\nCAS*", and put "5" after "CAS", so the line becomes "DM*72\nCAS5*", it still returns it, although now it has a digit after "CAS", so it shouldn't return it. It's just one of the scenarios that might happen.

Comment: My bad, then in that case not to use the named group.  I'll update the answer, please see.

Comment: If this resolved your problem, please consider accepting the answer to promote useful content for future visitors.  If you find issue with the answer however do let me know.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it checks only the numbers and letters before CAS and HC, but you can easily modify it to after also:

```
print(df[~df['Desc'].str.contains('([0-9a-zA-Z]+CAS*)|([0-9a-zA-Z]+HC*)', regex=True)])

   ID          Desc
1   2      HC:83*20
3   4   DM*72\nCAS*
4   5  HC:564*CAS*5
```

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't return the 2nd row?

Comment: Because it contains both HC and CAS and CAS has 2 in front --  HC:5*2CASL

Comment: How can i modify the code so that it would be "either or"? i need it to return this row since one of the conditions is satisfied.